# Is there a way to change the label that displays inside a button using AngularJS?

Tags: angularjs

I have button code like this:

```
<button class="small float-right"
   data-ng-click="tag()"
   data-ng-disabled="qs.tag == true">
   Tag
</button>
```

Is there a way I could change this so it displays Tagged as the label the button is clicked and qs.tag = true and the displays Tag when I click the button again and qs.tag is false.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this `{{qs.tag?"Tagged":"Tag"}}`

Comment: Thanks. On the controller, what would you suggest as the best way to implement the tag() function. Is there some way in java to swap between true and false with just one command ?

Comment: Not sure what you are asking?

Comment: Sorry I didn't explain very well. I want to have it so that when I click the button the state of qs.tag changes from false>true or true>false. Not sure how to do that with the function in the best way.

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
Tag<span ng-show="qs.tag">ed</span>
```